# Android Picasso not able to get image but placeholder

Tags: android, picasso

I am unable to get Picasso work with `RecyclerView.Adapter`. It is loading placeholder but not the image from URL.

## Activity

```
public class NewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.NewsViewHolder> {

    private List<News> mNews;
    private Context    mContext;

    public NewsAdapter(List<News> mNews, Context mContext) {
        this.mNews = mNews;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public NewsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.news_list_item, parent, false);
        return new NewsViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NewsViewHolder holder, int position) {

        News news = mNews.get(position);

        holder.itemSection.setText(news.getmSectionName());
        holder.itemDate.setText(news.getmWebPublicationDate());
        holder.itemHeadline.setText(news.getmHeadline());
        Picasso.get().load(news.getmThumbnail()).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background).into(holder.itemThumbnail);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mNews.size();
    }

    /**
     * ViewHolder Class
     */
    public class NewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView  itemSection;
        public TextView  itemDate;
        public TextView  itemHeadline;
        public ImageView itemThumbnail;
        public TextView  itemContributor;

        public NewsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            itemSection = itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_item_section);
            itemDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_item_date);
            itemHeadline = itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_item_headline);
            itemThumbnail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_item_thumbnail);
            itemContributor = itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_item_contributor);
        }
    }

}
```

## News Class

```
public class News {

    private String mSectionName;
    private String mWebPublicationDate;
    private String mWebUrl;
    private String mHeadline;
    private String mThumbnail;
    private String mWebTitle;
    private String mPillarName;

    public News(String mSectionName, String mWebPublicationDate, String mWebUrl, String mHeadline, String mThumbnail, String mWebTitle, String mPillarName) {
        this.mSectionName = mSectionName;
        this.mWebPublicationDate = mWebPublicationDate;
        this.mWebUrl = mWebUrl;
        this.mHeadline = mHeadline;
        this.mThumbnail = mThumbnail;
        this.mWebTitle = mWebTitle;
        this.mPillarName = mPillarName;
    }

    public String getmSectionName() {
        return mSectionName;
    }

    public String getmWebPublicationDate() {
        return mWebPublicationDate;
    }

    public String getmWebUrl() {
        return mWebUrl;
    }

    public String getmHeadline() {
        return mHeadline;
    }

    public String getmThumbnail() {
        return mThumbnail;
    }

    public String getmWebTitle() {
        return mWebTitle;
    }

    public String getmPillarName() {
        return mPillarName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "News{" +
                "mSectionName='" + mSectionName + '\'' +
                ", mWebPublicationDate='" + mWebPublicationDate + '\'' +
                ", mWebUrl='" + mWebUrl + '\'' +
                ", mHeadline='" + mHeadline + '\'' +
                ", mThumbnail='" + mThumbnail + '\'' +
                ", mWebTitle='" + mWebTitle + '\'' +
                ", mPillarName='" + mPillarName + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: did you add the internet permission in your manifest?

Comment: Oh probably that could be the reason. let me check

Comment: Wow.. resolved. that was the issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No prob! Definitely easy to forget to do